# react-select: How to keep menu closed after selecting a value when multiselect?

Tags: react-select

I would like the menu to be closed after I have selected a value in multi select mode.

Is that possible? I have tried scrollMenuIntoView={false} and openOnFocus={false} without success.

Thanks
/Torbjörn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got answer in another forum, 
"To close the whole control, you can keep a ref to the Select and call this.refs.select.closeMenu()."
https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1262